# Best method to connect lines in image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I need help to choose me a method which I can apply to my problem. Problem is I have 2 images like this
[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BOtn.jpg) and [Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TWRh.jpg).
You can see these are images with same same lines, not all lines. I would like you to suggest me a method how to approach this problem. I need to have best match possible and to have the coordinates for these to images how to put them together again, without matching them or using an algorithm again. Btw I prefer python like a programing language for this problem and please do not suggest patented method like surf etc.

Thank you for all answers and help from you.

Have a nice a day.

Comment: What do you mean by *"you need to have best match possible without matching them or using an algorithm again"*? How did you match them the first time? How do you hope to match them again without using an algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help). Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some research effort on your own (Google and StackOverflow searches), (2) learn what are appropriate questions and (3) show your code. Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your specific problem. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to have best match possible and to have the coordinates for these to images how to put them together again, **without matching them or using an algorithm again**

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by the highlighted part, but what you're describing seems to be an [image stitching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching) problem, or a least part of one.

OpenCV has a [class that implements a stitching pipeline](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/introduction.html).

If you are only interested in finding the correspondences and not the combined image, you could have a look [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html), where they explain a feature matcher and extractor.

Note, however, that the performance of these feature extractors depends a lot on the parameters you set, so you might have to tune them a bit before it works well.

Comment: You are right,  I need stitched images in final, but somehow I should get coordinates for both pictures, how to put them that lines match.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/high_level.html#Stitcher here the estimate transformation function would give you the approximate transformation between the images, which you can use to transform coordinates from one image to another. Whether it will work well in your case is hard so say without trying.